# Selenium not Clicking Link

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to reset modem with selenium. But I am facing a problem. I am trying to click but no click operation has been done. modem click is zyxel.

```
<li style="cursor: pointer;" class="subItem" id="maintenance-reboot"><span class="arrow">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a>Reboot</a></li>
```

I tried

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Reboot")).Click();
```

I also tried with id "maintenance-reboot" but nothing work for me.

Then I try to go directly link.

```
http://192.168.1.1/pages/maintenance/reboot/reboot.html
```

page came but no frame only reboot page and I clicked button but nothing change.
I think the mainframe required for reboot.

Comment: Can't load http://192.168.1.1/pages/maintenance/reboot/reboot.html . Can you copy the HTML from that page and add it to your question?

Comment: @NoSuchElephantException did you really tried to load that page? :)

Comment: @Thomas No, I'm just being polite. Even if someone did try to load it (I'm sure people have clicked thru), are you really going to snark at a person on Stack Overflow for not knowing something?

Comment: @NoSuchElephantException No, I'm not. Your phrase `Can't load 192.168.1.1[...]` just made my day when I was sad yesterday, I'm sorry if the way I wrote it made you think that I was mocking you. Hope you'll get my answer before it'll be removed as *too chatty* and I sincerely apologies if I hurt you.

Answer (score -1):

try this 3 things:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//li[@id='maintenance-reboot']/a")).Click();
```

or

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'Reboot')]/..")).Click();
```

or

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'Reboot')]/../..")).Click();
```

one of them must work for you

---

Alter solution: go to the page and execute Javascript "btnReset();"

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("btnReset();");
```

Comment: yeah it worked but I in this page a button <input name="sysSubmit" value="Yeniden başlat" onclick="btnReset()" type="button"> not working in button